# Can ImageMagick return the image size?

Tags: image, unix, image-processing, command-line, imagemagick

I'm using ImageMagick from the command line to resize images:

```
convert -size 320x240 image.jpg
```

However, I don't know how to determine the size of the final image. Since this is a proportional image scale, it's very possible that new image is 100x240 or 320x90 in size (not 320x240).

Can I call the 'convert' command to resize the image and return the new image dimensions? For example, pseudo code:

```
convert -size 320x240 -return_new_image_dimension image.jpg   // returns the new resized image dimensions
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You could use an extra call to `identify`:

```
convert -size 320x240 image.jpg; identify -format "%[fx:w]x%[fx:h]" image.jpg
```

Comment: curious, why is `identify -format "%[fx:w]x%[fx:h]"` preferable to `identify -format "%[w]x%[h]"` ?

Comment: I think it is not, @mark. I cannot imagine that back in 2009 the `%w` and `%h` were not supported yet. But if `fx:` has some side effect, then I guess I would have mentioned that as well. Weird. I will do some testing...

Answer (score 61):

**`-ping` option**

This option is also recommended as it prevents the entire image from being loaded to memory, as mentioned at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22393926/895245:

```
identify -ping -format '%w %h' image.jpg
```

`man identify` says:

```
-ping                efficiently determine image attributes
```

We can for example test it out with some of the humongous images present on [Wikimedia's "Large image" category](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Large_images) e.g. this [ultra high resolution image of Van Gogh's Starry Night](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Van_Gogh_-_Starry_Night_-_Google_Art_Project-x0-y0.jpg) which Wikimedia claims is 29,696 × 29,696 pixels, file size: 175.67 MB:

```
wget -O image.jpg https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e8/Van_Gogh_-_Starry_Night_-_Google_Art_Project-x0-y0.jpg
time identify -ping -format '%w %h' image.jpg
time identify       -format '%w %h' image.jpg
```

I however observed that `-ping` at least in this case did not make any difference on the time, maybe it only matters for other image formats?

Tested on ImageMagick 6.9.10, Ubuntu 20.04.

See also: [Fast way to get image dimensions (not filesize)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670013/fast-way-to-get-image-dimensions-not-filesize)

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure with the `%w` and `%h` format. While Photoshop says my picture is 2678x3318 (and I really trust Photoshop), `identify` gives me:

```
identify -ping -format '=> %w %h' image.jpg
=> 643x796
```

(so does [fx:w] and [fx:h])

I had to use

```
identify -ping -format '=> %[width] %[height]' image.jpg
=> 2678x3318
```

I don't know what's going on here, but you can see both values on standard output (where the width and height *before* the => are the correct ones)

```
identify -ping image.jpg
image.jpg PAM 2678x3318=>643x796 643x796+0+0 16-bit ColorSeparation CMYK 2.047MB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

[The documentation](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/escape.php) says %w is the *current* width and %[width] is *original* width. Confusing.

`%w` and `%h` may be correct for most uses, but not for every picture.

Answer (score 1):

If you specify option `-verbose`, convert prints:

```
original.jpg=>scaled.jpg JPEG 800x600=>100x75 100x75+0+0 8-bit sRGB 4.12KB 0.020u 0:00.009
                                       ^^^^^^
```

Comment: I want to read the width of the magick file using magick and then resize it such that height always remains 900pixel. I tried to use magick resize identify -format '%wx2' urban7.jpg but it fails. I am on Windows system so if any batch commands are there , i could use some. Please help. I came across this but could not understand it ```https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56672830/how-to-resize-an-image-in-imagemagick-but-keep-an-aspect-ratio-constant/56673304#56673304```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in Imagemagick as follows:

```
convert input.jpg -resize 320x240 -write output.jpg -format "%wx%h\n" info:
```