# Fast way to get image dimensions (not filesize)

Tags: linux, image

I'm looking for a **fast** way to get the height and width of an image in pixels. It should handle at least JPG, PNG and TIFF, but the more the better. I emphasize *fast* because my images are quite big (up to 250 MB) and it takes soooo long to get the size with ImageMagick's `identify` because it obviously reads the images as a whole first.

Preferably, I look for a way that works well in Ruby, or even in Rails 3.

I know the theory stuff (various image formats, their headers and their differences, and so on). Indeed, I ask for some kind of library that can resolve my issue in a fairly generic way.

I just found [imagesize](https://rubygems.org/gems/imagesize/) which looks promising although development seems to be dead.

Comment: This does not seem to be true for new versions of ImageMagick. Using ImageMagick 6.5.4-7 I have confirmed that identify (at least for TIF and PNG) only reads the header (up to 60KB) and works very fast, even for 335MB images.

Answer (score 212):

- The `file` command prints the dimensions for several image formats (e.g. PNG, GIF, JPEG; recent versions also PPM, WEBP), and does only read the header.
- **The `identify` command** (from ImageMagick) prints lots of image information for a wide variety of images. It seems to restrain itself to reading the header portion (see comments). It also uses a unified format which `file` sadly lacks.
- `exiv2` gives you dimensions for many formats, including JPEG, TIFF, PNG, GIF, WEBP, even if no EXIF header present. It is unclear if it reads the whole data for that though. See the manpage of exiv2 for all supported image formats.
- `head -n1` will give you the dimensions for PPM, PGM formats.

For formats popular on the web, both `exiv2` and `identify` will do the job.
Depending on the use-case you may need to write your own script that combines/parses outputs of several tools.

Comment: I have done some tests with the ImageMagick identify command, using strace to record open/read/mmap/close calls to see how much data was been read from the identified image. It does depend on the file type and file size slightly, but I was getting 20-60 KB read by "identify" for 5-335 MB images (I also tested against "convert" which showed all bytes being read). So it looks like "identify" is a good choice here (since it supports all popular formats and reads just the header).

Comment: I think exiv2 also does PNG.

Comment: Any ways to parse that file commands output easily? Identify is great but it doesn't work with WebP files sadly

Comment: Identify *does* work with WebP, and ImageMagick has support for WebP for years. Maybe you could get an update?

Comment: Passing the `--brief` option to the `file` command will prevent it from outputting the filename, which will likely make the rest of the output easier to parse.

Answer (score 34):

I not sure you have php installed, but this PHP function is pretty handy

```
 php -r "print_r(getimagesize('http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png'));"
```

Comment: This is much faster than "identify". Good approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 26):

You can use ImageMagick's [identify](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php) function. Here's how you do it in bash (Note $0 is the image's path):

```
width=$(identify -format "%w" "$0")> /dev/null
height=$(identify -format "%h" "$0")> /dev/null
```

And this also hides any potential error messages. Modern implementations of `identify` only read the header, not the whole image, so it is fast. Not sure how it compares to other methods though.

Comment: I believe it's much more efficient this way: `read width height < <(identify -format "%w %h" "${1}")`

Answer (score 4):

https://joseluisbz.wordpress.com/2013/08/06/obtaining-size-or-dimension-of-images/ (BMP, PNG, GIF, JPG, TIF or WMF)

Here for two formats PNG and JPG.

<sup>My code is from a class designed to my use, you can to edit according to your needs.</sup>

Please check these functions/method using **PHP**:

```
  public function ByteStreamImageString($ByteStream,&$Formato,&$Alto,&$Ancho) {
    $Alto = 0;
    $Ancho = 0;
    $Formato = -1;
    $this->HexImageString = "Error";
    if (ord($ByteStream[0])==137 && ord($ByteStream[1])==80 && ord($ByteStream[2])==78){
      $Formato = 1; //PNG
      $Alto = $this->Byte2PosInt($ByteStream[22],$ByteStream[23]);
      $Ancho = $this->Byte2PosInt($ByteStream[18],$ByteStream[19]);
    }
    if (ord($ByteStream[0])==255 && ord($ByteStream[1])==216
        && ord($ByteStream[2])==255 && ord($ByteStream[3])==224){
      $Formato = 2; //JPG
      $PosJPG = 2;
      while ($PosJPG<strlen($ByteStream)){
        if (sprintf("%02X%02X", ord($ByteStream[$PosJPG+0]),ord($ByteStream[$PosJPG+1]))=="FFC0"){
          $Alto = $this->Byte2PosInt($ByteStream[$PosJPG+5],$ByteStream[$PosJPG+6]);
          $Ancho = $this->Byte2PosInt($ByteStream[$PosJPG+7],$ByteStream[$PosJPG+8]);
        }
        $PosJPG = $PosJPG+2+$this->Byte2PosInt($ByteStream[$PosJPG+2],$ByteStream[$PosJPG+3]);
      }
    }
    if ($Formato > 0){
      $this->HexImageString = "";
      $Salto = 0;
      for ($i=0;$i < strlen($ByteStream); $i++){
        $Salto++;
        $this->HexImageString .= sprintf("%02x", ord($ByteStream[$i]));
        if ($Salto==64){
          $this->HexImageString .= "\n";
          $Salto = 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }


  private function Byte2PosInt($Byte08,$Byte00) {
    return ((ord($Byte08) & 0xFF) << 8)|((ord($Byte00) & 0xFF) << 0);
  }
```

Using the PHP Code:

```
      $iFormato = NULL;//Format PNG or JPG
      $iAlto = NULL; //High
      $iAncho = NULL;//Wide
      ByteStreamImageString($ImageJPG,$iFormato,$iAlto,$iAncho);//The Dimensions will stored in  iFormato,iAlto,iAncho
```

Now these functions/method using **JAVA**:

```
  private void ByteStreamImageString(byte[] ByteStream,int[] Frmt,int[] High,int[] Wide) {
    High[0] = 0;
    Wide[0] = 0;
    Frmt[0] = -1;
    this.HexImageString = "Error";
    if ((int)(ByteStream[0]&0xFF)==137 && (int)(ByteStream[1]&0xFF)==80 &&(int)(ByteStream[2]&0xFF)==78){
      Frmt[0] = 1; //PNG
      High[0] = this.Byte2PosInt(ByteStream[22],ByteStream[23]);
      Wide[0] = this.Byte2PosInt(ByteStream[18],ByteStream[19]);
    }
    if ((int)(ByteStream[0]&0xFF)==255 && (int)(ByteStream[1]&0xFF)==216
        &&(int)(ByteStream[2]&0xFF)==255 && (int)(ByteStream[3]&0xFF)==224){
      Frmt[0] = 2; //JPG
      int PosJPG = 2;
      while (PosJPG<ByteStream.length){
        if (String.format("%02X%02X", ByteStream[PosJPG+0],ByteStream[PosJPG+1]).equals("FFC0")){
          High[0] = this.Byte2PosInt(ByteStream[PosJPG+5],ByteStream[PosJPG+6]);
          Wide[0] = this.Byte2PosInt(ByteStream[PosJPG+7],ByteStream[PosJPG+8]);
        }
        PosJPG = PosJPG+2+this.Byte2PosInt(ByteStream[PosJPG+2],ByteStream[PosJPG+3]);
      }
    }
    if (Frmt[0] > 0){
      this.HexImageString = "";
      int Salto = 0;
      for (int i=0;i < ByteStream.length; i++){
        Salto++;
        this.HexImageString += String.format("%02x", ByteStream[i]);
        if (Salto==64){
          this.HexImageString += "\n";
          Salto = 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }


  private Integer Byte2PosInt(byte Byte08, byte Byte00) {
    return new Integer (((Byte08 & 0xFF) << 8)|((Byte00 & 0xFF) << 0));
  }
```

Using the Java code:

```
        int[] iFormato = new int[1]; //Format PNG or JPG
        int[] iAlto = new int[1]; //High
        int[] iAncho = new int[1]; //Wide
        ByteStreamImageString(ImageJPG,iFormato,iAlto,iAncho); //The Dimensions will stored in  iFormato[0],iAlto[0],iAncho[0]
```

Comment: I see you're using arrays for arguments as a hack to get `ref`/`out` parameters in Java - is that considered best-practice?

Comment: This answer is very old, now I'm not willing to update (I'm forget a lot things and I haven't time), but you can to check the code and edit it.

Comment: https://joseluisbz.wordpress.com/2013/07/26/exploring-a-wmf-file-0x000900/ (explanation for WMF)

Comment: For this example I recommend implements a new class with 3 fields, Format, High and Width, returning a instance of this class.

Answer (score 3):

**Imagemagick `-ping` option**

It seems to have been introduced for that purpose.

However as of ImageMagick 6.7.7 I don't observe slowdown even for every large files, e.g.:

```
head -c 100000000 /dev/urandom > f.gray
# I don't recommend that you run this command as it eats a lot of memory.
convert -depth 8 -size 20000x10000 f.gray f.png
identify f.png
```

Can you produce an example input image for which it is still slow?

See also: [Can ImageMagick return the image size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555509/can-imagemagick-return-the-image-size)

Answer (score 1):

It's the pixel dimensions you want (width and height), I assume?

I'd think that most file formats have some header info defining the dimensions, so that the software reading the file can know how much room it must reserve before starting to read the file. Some "raw" type file formats might just be a stream of bytes with some "end of line" byte at the end of each horizontal row of pixels (in which case the software must read the first line and divide the size of the byte stream by the line length to get the height).

I don't think you can make this in any "generic" way, as you need to understand the file format (or use a library of course) in order to know how to read it. You can probably find some code that will in most cases give a rough estimate of the dimensions without reading the whole file, but I think some filetypes may require you to read the whole file to be sure what dimensions it really have. I expect that most web centric image formats have a header with such info so that the browser can create the box dimensions before the whole image is loaded.

I'd guess a good library would have some methods to get the dimensions of the files it handles, and that those methods would be implemented as efficient as possible.

*Update*: [imageinfo](http://linux.die.net/man/1/imageinfo) seems like it does what you want. (Have not tested it)

Comment: That tool works as fast as i need it ;). I'll see if i can use it properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have EXIF information in the images, you can just read the EXIF header.

Comment: Unfortunatly I don't know what kind of images there will be and whether they have EXIF data.

Comment: How many of your images *DO* have that information?  Maybe if 90% of them have EXIF data then the slowness of using ImageMagick on the other 10% will be acceptable.

Comment: Why does this answer have downvotes? It's a valid answer to the question and may well be exactly what the OP or someone else is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

tldr: file "imagename" will do

works with webp, all jpg formats (jpeg,jpg200,..),

Sample output looks like

> JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.02, aspect ratio, density 1x1,
>   segment length 16, baseline, precision 8, 650x400, frames 3

load the output of file to a python list & use the 4'th field in the list.

FYI, did optimize around 18000+ images to cut down network traffic.