# Get image dimensions using batch script (ImageMagick)

Tags: batch-file, imagemagick

What I'm trying to do is use ImageMagick to create a border on an image.
It's a simple process, I can do it manually with hard-coded values, but I want it to be smart.
What it needs to do, is to be able to simply define what image you want the border on, then the script is to run through, get the dimensions of the image, then resize the border image I have to those dimensions, and slap the border on the top.

To do so, from my basic understanding, I'll have to store the width and height from the image as variables. The closest I've gotten (actually getting the info) is

```
identify "image.png"
```

That spits out the info that I need, but I need to store the width/height into variables to use them in later processes.
I found the following code from https://superuser.com/questions/323970/how-can-i-get-the-image-dimensions-of-a-targa-file-through-a-batch-script

(NOTE: My .bat file is called "imagecheck.bat"

```
identify -format "imagecheck2.bat %w %h" image.png > temp.bat
temp.bat
```

From what the poster of that code said, it will get the width and height (%w and %h) from image.png, then store it in imagecheck2.bat as variables that I can access as %1 (for %w) and %2 (for %h)

So, with that being said, inside imagecheck2.bat, I had

```
@echo off
echo The parameters were: %1 and %2
pause
```

And it prints out

```
The parameters were:  and
```

This should be such a simple thing; any ideas what I'm missing?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you have two `imagecheck` batch files? Couldn't you just take away the `> temp.bat` and have the output as soon as you call the command?

Comment: The code above was simply pulled from the link, and then I modified it a little to be more like what I had.
And I couldn't manage to get the outputs after ImageMagick's command had finished.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555509/can-imagemagick-return-the-image-size

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a way that this can be done without the use of any auxiliary files.

```
for /f "tokens=1-2" %%i in ('identify -ping -format "%%w %%h" logo:') do set W=%%i & set H=%%j
echo width: %W%
echo height: %H%
```

Replace "logo:" with the filename of your image.

That said, I strongly recommend not using MS Batch, as the more complex your program gets, the more ridiculous the code will get.

By the way, the use of the `-ping` flag in that identify command greatly speeds up the operation because it tells identify not to load the whole image into memory, just enough of it to figure out the dimensions.

Comment: You're a genius! Thanks so much man

Also, the only reason I'm using batch, is because in the end all of this will be operated by PHP and

1) It's easier to write these in batch (for me at least)

2) From what I understand, it's much faster to do the one system() call to run the batch file, than it is to run each system() call for each of ImageMagick's commands that I'd need for some of my operations.

Also, I can't get layering/masking to work through PHP's system() due to PHP's string limitations, but it works fine through the commands in the batch file.

Comment: Ah. In that case, I recommend first abandoning Batch, then abandoning PHP ;-)  Thx for the vote.

Comment: Haha I would happily abandon PHP if this wasn't for work purposes

Comment: Does the `-ping` advice still hold today? I'm new to ImageMagick and can't find it in the [docs](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php) (there at least)

Comment: @watery It is documented here: https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#ping

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using ImageMagick, you can simply pull the width and height out of the PNG.  They are in known locations and each is a 4-byte integer in network byte order (most significant byte first).  The offsets from the beginning of the file are

```
 signature:   bytes 0-7
 IHDR length: bytes 8-11
 "IHDR":      bytes 12-15
 width:       bytes 16-19
 height:      bytes 20-23
```

Comment: It's not the same order for each different file type is it?
PNG is the primary file type, but there is a very strong chance of bitmaps, jpegs and targa's down the track (unfortunately).

Comment: This answer was specific to PNG, as your question seemed to be.  For various types of images, "identify" will find the dimensions, as described in the answer from retroj.

Comment: It does do what I asked, that was my bad; still definitely useful though. Thanks :)